# grails ajax works with a form and create but not with edit

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I'm using grails for a traffic project. It's my first with grails!

I have a domain *Station* with two boolean values *hasroad* and *hasrail*. In the station controller I use this method:

```
def hasroadhasrail() {
    def station = Station.get(params.stationid)

    def response = ['hasroad': station?.hasroad, 'hasrail': station?.hasrail]
    render response as JSON
}
```

Then I have a domain *Traffic* which is linked to Station with

```
Station station
```

with lots of data. If there can't be road/rails data the input fields are disabled and greyed out.

I'm using *jquery 1.8.0*

The ajax call in the _*form.gsp* of traffic looks like this:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // correct for create
            $("input.data1").prop('disabled', ${trafficInstance?.station?.hasroad ?: true});
            $("input.data2").prop('disabled', ${trafficInstance?.station?.hasrail ?: true});

            $("#station").change(function() {
                $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "${createLink(controller: 'station', action: 'hasroadhasrail')}",
                      data: { stationid: $(this).val()}
                    }).done(function( response ) {
                        if (response.hasroad) {
                            $("input.data1").prop('disabled', false);
                            $('input.data1').css('background-color', 'white');
                        } 
                        else {
                            $("input.data1").prop('disabled', true);
                            $('input.data1').css('background-color', 'grey');
                        }

                        if (response.hasrail) {
                            $("input.data2").prop('disabled', false);
                            $('input.data2').css('background-color', 'white');
                        } 
                        else {
                            $("input.data2").prop('disabled', true);
                            $('input.data2').css('background-color', 'grey');
                        } 
                    });
            });
        })
    </script>
```

and here is the dropdown for *Stations* also in the _*form.gsp* of traffic

```
    <li class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: trafficInstance, field: 'station', 'error')} required"> <span class="lbl">Station</span>
        <g:select id="station" name="station.id" from="${trafproj.Station.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${trafficInstance?.station?.id}" class="many-to-one" noSelection="['':'-Choose station-']"/>
    </li>
```

When I create new traffic data all works perfectly. I chose a station from the dropdown and if for example *hasroad* is false for this station the input fields are disabled and greyed out. **All above code works great!**

Now my problem: If I edit previously created traffic a station is already loaded in the station dropdown. There is no change and therefore the ajax doesn't work instantly. When I change the station in the dropdown again all works fine.

What do I have to add that the dropdown not only works on change but also when a station was initially loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the ajax function into a separate function, instead of an anonymous, inline function.

Then call that function from document.ready() in addition to using it as the onchange handler.

Be sure to change

```
data: { stationid: $(this).val()}
```

to

```
data: { stationid: $("#station").val()}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are doing the ajax call only when the content of your station change. This event not fires when the page load. To do that, wrap the logic in a function and call inside the change and once when the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ...
  function getStationData() {
    $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "${createLink(controller: 'station', action: 'hasroadhasrail')}",
                  data: { stationid: $(this).val()}
                }).done(function( response ) {
                    if (response.hasroad) {
                        $("input.data1").prop('disabled', false);
                        $('input.data1').css('background-color', 'white');
                    } 
                    else {
                        $("input.data1").prop('disabled', true);
                        $('input.data1').css('background-color', 'grey');
                    }

                    if (response.hasrail) {
                        $("input.data2").prop('disabled', false);
                        $('input.data2').css('background-color', 'white');
                    } 
                    else {
                        $("input.data2").prop('disabled', true);
                        $('input.data2').css('background-color', 'grey');
                    } 
                });
  }

  $('#station').change(function(){
    getStationData();
  });

  //call this first time when page loads.
  getStationData();
});
```

Comment: I did indeed needed this data: { stationid: $("#station").val()}. Otherwise it didn't work. Nevertheless thanks for your posting!